# Count Duplicate Results in Oracle Database

Tags: java, sql, database

I am working on a database project using both Java and SQL with an Oracle Database. I am new at working with databases and new at SQL. My question is: how would I be able to get the customer count and record each of their purchase history on a pivot table? For example, on the following table, I have Lee a total of 3 times, and purchased Item A, Item B, and Item C. Ann is there 3 times as well and purchased Item D, Item E, and Item F. I want to put their name, the number of occurrences and what they purchased on separate pivot table.

```
Row       Customer      Purchase_History
 1          Lee              Item A
 2          Lee              Item B
 3          Lee              Item C
 4          Ann              Item D
 5          Ann              Item E
 6          Ann              Item F
```

I've written some code attempting to do this, but when I compile and run, it will not give me the desired results. Here is my code:

```
           String TableCount = "SELECT J.Row, J.Customer, J.Purchase_History, C.cnt" +
                " FROM Table J INNER JOIN(SELECT Customer, count(Customer) as cnt" +
                "FROM Table GROUP BY Customer") C ON J.Customer = C.Customer;
         ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(TableCount);


         while(rs.next()){

             st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER_COUNT" +
                        "(TableCount  , Purchase_History )");
            String InsertIntoTable = String.format("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_COUNT" +
                        "("TableCount","Purchase_History")" +
                        " VALUES ('%s','%s)");
         }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query logic is fine.  You should print out the query before running it.  The problem would be these two lines (at least):

```
            " FROM Table J INNER JOIN(SELECT Customer, count(Customer) as cnt" +
            "FROM Table GROUP BY Customer") C ON J.Customer = C.Customer;
```

I assume you really mean:

```
            " FROM Table J INNER JOIN(SELECT Customer, count(Customer) as cnt" +
            "FROM Table GROUP BY Customer) C ON J.Customer = C.Customer";
```

In any case, when you print this out, you'll have the expression `cntFROM table`.  You need a space:

```
            " FROM Table J INNER JOIN(SELECT Customer, count(Customer) as cnt" +
            " FROM Table GROUP BY Customer) C ON J.Customer = C.Customer";
```

But, an easier way to write your query is to use analytic functions:

```
select J.Row, J.Customer, J.Purchase_History,
       count(*) over (partition by customer) as cnt
from table j
```

Comment: This was very helpful..Thanks for your help Gordon! I appreciate it.